# Do only sentient being suffer

Tags: suffering, buddha-nature, unconditioned

All I can think of off the top of mind head is the zen claim that mountains are buddha nature. Do they suffer? They are composed of parts, and I believe that there is a type of suffering from "conditioned existence", in Pali.

Comment: i mean i don't think i could have been born as a rock. but i think i could die unonscious. just thinking out loud

Comment: Suffering is a kind of meaning-making. If there's semiosis - there can be suffering. Semiosis is not limited to sentient beings or even to living beings, but it does require some kind of functional ecosystem, I think. So the current destructive processes in the Earth's ecosystem are a kind of suffering inasmuch as they interfere with natural semiosis, IMO.

Comment: i have no opinion on anything anymore... there's too manny, and too much weeirdness

Answer (score 1):

> Is a mountain heavy?
>
> It may be heavy in and of itself, but as long as we don't try to lift it up, it won't be heavy for us. ... *[The Weight of Mountains](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/mountains_en.html)*

My person thinks that householder goes after every, even foolish thought and does not scare to even let it become speech. The serial of questions found is amazing... Don't he like to train a little of letting go of useless thoughts, don't giving them attention, otherwise they are just further nourished, wasting time and resources: causing suffering even not aware.

Better reflecting on mountains in this way: [The Simile of the Mountains](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.025.than_en.html), for it helps not to wast hard gained human existence.

*[note that this isn't giving for entertaining, stacks, exchange and other world-binding trades but for escape from this wheel]*

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that there is a type of suffering from "conditioned existence", in Pali

Assuming you're thinking of a phrase like *sabbe sankhara dukkha*, I think that's usually translated as, something like, "all conditioned things are unsatisfactory".

That's not saying that mountains feel dissatisfaction themselves -- I think it's saying that sentient beings (i.e. who have "feelings" and who perceive "mountains" etc.) can't find things such as mountains to be a permanent source of satisfaction.

See also topics like:

- [Why is 'dukkha' included in one of the three marks of existence?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/41074/254)
- [Differences between the tilakkhana and the Dhamma seal](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/19038/254)

Comment: i'm not saying mountains have feelings. i mean, feeling is a specific thing, it's noty the same as suffering

Answer (score 0):

> Do only sentient being suffer?

Not all sentient beings suffer.Those who have attained Nirvana do not suffer at all. They are freed from suffering.

> All I can think of off the top of mind head is the zen claim that
> mountains are buddha nature. Do they suffer? They are composed of
> parts, and I believe that there is a type of suffering from
> "conditioned existence", in Pali.

I have not read anything Zen but Buddha Nature is free of suffering. You asked Do mountains suffer ? That is not the right way to look at it. Suppose anyone believes I am mountains then he is bound to suffer. Ordinary person may even believe I am Earth but such a belief can not end suffering because sabbe Dhamma Anatta i.e Earth is not me , mine or myself.(Same applies to Water , Air , Fire etc)

Comment: does the buddha nature exist apart from phenomena, though?

Comment: @satirical_buddhist  Buddha nature is the nature of nirvana. It is the nature of unborn, uncreate ,unbecoming, unoriginated, unformed. Phenomenon and thoughts are Anatta...